# I am trying to implement a webview preview just like youtube app has on click of a button

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to figure out how to implement this feature in a listview of android:

https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ir1xdtIb-g0/maxresdefault.jpg

Please help me to sort this out.

Comment: You should explain more about the behaviour you expect also post some code that you tried to implement.

Comment: updated my question. Please check and let me know how to implement it.